# Manage tenants in api manager 2.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We are using wso2 api manager 2.1.0 and we need using tenant. 
Searching in documentation we saw differences in 2.1.0 vs 2.0.0.

Are tenants supported in api manager 2.1.0?
Are all the tenant management functions available in api manager 2.1.0?

Is there any configuration that we have to do?
Would we do something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multitenancy is supported in both versions and all tenant features are the same in both.

You don't have to do any configuration changes.

Update: Doc is now updated with new links.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+Multiple+Tenants

Comment: Why in the documentation of api manager 2.1.0 you never talk about removing tenant?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Multi-tenant+Architecture returns **Page Not Found**, it's only available at 2.0.0 Space (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Multi-tenant+Architecture)

Comment: It's updated now. See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+Multiple+Tenants